# VSTS Build + Azure Database + Redgate ReadyRoll

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, readyroll

I'm trying to make a CI/CD pipeline for my database on VSTS and deploy it on an Azure SQL Server using Redgate ReadyRoll. But I'm stuck at the build process.
Here are the tasks I use :

- Setup a Shadow DB

[image]

- Build solution

[image]

- Copy Publish Artifact

Here are the variables used :

[image]

But at the second task (Build solution), I have an issue to connect to the Azure Database :

```
packages\ReadyRoll.MSBuild.1.14.7.4267\tools\ReadyRoll.Data.Schema.SSDT.targets(145,5): Error : An error occurred while attempting to verify your deployment scripts: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

The login/password are correct, I checked multiple times.
I tried the Hosted agent as well as a private agent (on my own machine) but I have the same error.

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Sounds a bit vendor specific.  Have you tried contacting redgate?

Comment: Yes but still no answer from Redgate.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about getting an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks !
Here is the link of my question on the Redgate website : [link](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/81350/vsts-build-azure-database)

Comment: Do you add [firewall rule to Azure SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure)? Could you connect to Azure SQL Server from your machine?

Comment: What's the result if you call MSBuild command to deploy database on your local machine manually?

Comment: Is the database (can be empty) existing on Azure SQL Server?

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you share the detail build log here or on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 1):

You can check these things:

1. ShadowServer login account, it uses build service account if you don’t specify ShadowUserName and ShadowPassword. So go to local service > Double click build agent service> Change to your account
2. Azure SQL Server firewall rule. (The Hosted agent IP is not in Azure SQL Server firewall rule, you can add your private build agent IP to Azure SQL Server firewall rule and queue build with your build agent)